# How to pass data to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. I have two queries to show separate tables in the same view.

One is

```
 var query = from s in db.tblSites
                        where s.SiteStatus== 1
                        select s;
```

and the other one is

```
var query2 = from s in db.tblSites
                            where s.SiteStatus== 0
                            select s;
```

So I' going to use the `@Html.RenderPartial`

But I don't know how to pass the data.

I want to pass the `query2` data to my partial view.

```
 @Html.Partial("RemoveContract",--------) //I don't know how to pass data.
```

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult AddContract(int id)
        {
            var query = from s in db.tblSites
                            where s.SiteStatus== 1
                            select s;

    var query2 = from s in db.tblSites
                                where s.SiteStatus== 0
                                select s;

            return View(query .ToList());

        }
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `query2` to the `ViewBag` of the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult AddContract(int id)
{
    ...
    this.ViewBag.Query2 = query2;
    return View(query .ToList());
}
```

And then just pass the view model you want the partial view to render as a parameter using the overloads of the [`Partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402902%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method.

```
@Html.Partial("RemoveContract", ViewBag.Query2)
```

*NOTE*: Depending on your setup, you may need to use `this.ViewBag.Query2 = query2.ToList()` to materialize the query before passing it on to the view.

Comment: I can't understand.I want to pass the query2 to partial view.

Comment: @user1348351 Sorry, I didn't understand the issue at first. I updated the answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the `Model` to `@Html.Partial`

```
@Html.Partial("RemoveContract",Model)
```

If you were to pass the query2 to your partial then you need to do like this:

```
public ActionResult AddContract(int id)
        {
            var query = from s in db.tblSites
                            where s.SiteStatus== 1
                            select s;

    var query2 = from s in db.tblSites
                                where s.SiteStatus== 0
                                select s;

//return View(query .ToList());
return View(query2 .ToList());


        }
```